# Smart contract always returns the same hash even when provided with different input

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x

I created a basic smart contract and Im using ganache locally but when i call it with different inputs it always returns the same value, has anyone come across this before ?

```
        contract.randomHash(34444444).then( async (hash) => { 
            console.log({hash}) 
            const eventFilter = contract.filters.Random();
            const events = await contract.queryFilter(eventFilter);
            const eventData = events[0].args;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(eventData))
        })
```

and the contract

```
        // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
        pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


        contract Random {
            
        event Random(bytes32 indexed _randomizer);    


            function randomHash(uint256 externalRandom) public {
                bytes32 _swapID = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, externalRandom, block.timestamp, block.number, gasleft()));
                emit Random(_swapID);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Hi , try this code : bytes32 _swapID = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, externalRandom, block.timestamp, blockhash(block.number), gasleft()));

Comment: No it doesnt work, it doesnt matter how many times i call the contract or using different external input it always produces the same event

Comment: You can use ChainLink VRF, it is safer and has a ready algorithm, and you only need to call it : https://docs.chain.link/getting-started/intermediates-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The function isn't a view function. When you execute it it should return the transaction hash.

```
function randomHash(uint256 externalRandom) public {
    bytes32 _swapID = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, externalRandom, block.timestamp, block.number, gasleft()));
    emit Random(_swapID);
}
```

In any case the EVM is not well suited to generate randomness.